# Animate dead command communication. How does it work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

*Animate Dead* creates minions that can be made to attack, and move.

Is this via talking, a free action? And therefore subject to the limitations of speech, which could be countered with something like *Zone of Silence*?

Or this more "force of will", making it harder to subvert?

Strictly by the official rules in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line of the spell description reads (emphasis mine):

> This spell turns corpses into undead skeletons or zombies **that obey your spoken commands**.

There is nothing in the Paizo FAQ to countermand this, so your answer seems pretty clear.